# Trouble merging Scraped data using Pandas and numpy in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect information from a lot of different urls and combine the data based on the year and Golfer name. As of now I am trying to write the information to csv and then match using pd.merge() but I have to use a unique name for each dataframe to merge. I tried to use a numpy array but I am stuck with the final process of getting all the separate data to be merged.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import socket
import urllib.error
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import sqlalchemy
import numpy as np

base = 'http://www.pgatour.com/'
inn = 'stats/stat'
end = '.html'
years = ['2017','2016','2015','2014','2013']

alpha = []
#all pages with links to tables
urls = ['http://www.pgatour.com/stats.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.ROTT_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RAPP_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RARG_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RPUT_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RSCR_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RSTR_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RMNY_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RPTS_INQ.html']
for i in urls:
    data = urlopen(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            alpha.append(base + link['href'][17:]) #may need adjusting
#data links
beta = []
for i in alpha:
    if inn in i:
        beta.append(i)
#no repeats
gamma= []
for i in beta:
    if i not in gamma:
        gamma.append(i)

#making list of urls with Statistic labels
jan = []
for i in gamma:
    try:
        data = urlopen(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
        for table in soup.find_all('section',{'class':'module-statistics-off-the-tee-details'}):
            for j in table.find_all('h3'):
                y=j.get_text().replace(" ","").replace("-","").replace(":","").replace(">","").replace("<","").replace(">","").replace(")","").replace("(","").replace("=","").replace("+","")
                jan.append([i,str(y+'.csv')])
                print([i,str(y+'.csv')])
    except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

# practice url
#jan = [['http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02356.html', 'Last15EventsScoring.csv']]
#grabbing data
#write to csv
row_sp = []
rows_sp =[]
title1 = [] 
title = []  
for i in jan:
    try:
        with open(i[1], 'w+') as fp:
            writer = csv.writer(fp)
            for y in years:
                data = urlopen(i[0][:-4] +y+ end)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
                data1 = urlopen(i[0])
                soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
                for table in soup1.find_all('table',{'id':'statsTable'}):
                    title.append('year')
                    for k in table.find_all('tr'):
                        for n in k.find_all('th'):
                            title1.append(n.get_text())
                            for l in title1:
                                if l not in title:
                                    title.append(l)
                    rows_sp.append(title)
                for table in soup.find_all('table',{'id':'statsTable'}):
                    for h in table.find_all('tr'):
                        row_sp = [y]
                        for j in h.find_all('td'):
                            row_sp.append(j.get_text().replace(" ","").replace("\n","").replace("\xa0"," ").replace("d",""))
                        rows_sp.append(row_sp)
                        print(row_sp)
                        writer.writerows([row_sp])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

dfs = [df1,df2,df3] # store dataframes in one list
df_merge = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['v1'], how='outer'), dfs)
```

The urls, stat types, desired format
the ... is just all of the stuff inbetween
trying to get the data on one row
urls for below data ['http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02356.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02568.html',...,'http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.111.html']

Statistics Titles

```
LAST 15 EVENTS - SCORING, SG: APPROACH-THE-GREEN, ..., SAND SAVE PERCENTAGE
year rankthisweek  ranklastweek   name         events   rating    rounds avg
2017 2             3             Rickie Fowler  10      8.8       62    .614    
TOTAL SG:APP   MEASURED ROUNDS   .... %     # SAVES    # BUNKERS    TOTAL O/U PAR
26.386         43                ....70.37    76           108          +7.00
```

Comment: Where in your code are you using pandas? Where is the attempted `merge`?

Comment: no attempt but it would be something like                                                   dataframes = [df1,df2,df3] # store in one list
df_merge = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['column'], how='outer'), dataframes), this is the process I was trying to complete but I cant make it to the point to utilize it

Comment: Why doesn't the chain merge work? Error? Undesired result? Are you not reading in csvs to dataframes?

Comment: turning csvs into dataframes requires a name for the dataframe the way I understand it so I am having trouble uniquely naming the dataframes to use the chain merge

Comment: You can loop through csv files iteratively run `read.csv()` and append to list or dict then run chain merge.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** (per comments)
This question is partly about technical methods (Pandas `merge()`), but it also seems like an opportunity to discuss useful workflows for data collection and cleaning.  As such I'm adding a bit more detail and explanation than what is strictly required for a coding solution.

You can basically use the same approach as my original answer to get data from different URL categories.  I'd recommend keeping a list of `{url:data}` dicts as you iterate over your URL list, and then building cleaned data frames from that dict.

There's a little legwork involved in setting up the cleaning portion, as you need to adjust for the different columns in each URL category.  I've demonstrated with a manual approach, using only a few tests URLs.  But if you have, say, thousands of different URL categories, then you may need to think about how to collect and organize column names programmatically.  That feels out of scope for this OP.

As long as you're sure there's a `year` and `PLAYER NAME` field in each URL, the following merge should work.  As before, let's assume that you don't need to write to CSV, and for now let's leave off making any optimizations to your scraping code:

First, define the url categories in `urls`.  By *url category* I'm referring to the fact that `http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02356.html` will actually be used multiple times by inserting a series of years into the url itself, e.g.: `http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02356.2017.html`, `http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02356.2016.html`. In this example, `stat.02356.html` is the url category that contains information about multiple years of player data.

```
import pandas as pd

# test urls given by OP
# note: each url contains >= 1 data fields not shared by the others
urls = ['http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02356.html',
        'http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02568.html',
        'http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.111.html']

# we'll store data from each url category in this dict.
url_data = {}
```

Now iterate over `urls`. Within the `urls` loop, this code is all the same as my original answer, which in turn is coming from OP - only with some variable names adjusted to reflect our new capturing method.

```
for url in urls:
    print("url: ", url)
    url_data[url] = {"row_sp": [],
                     "rows_sp": [],
                     "title1": [],
                     "title": []}
    try:
        #with open(i[1], 'w+') as fp:
            #writer = csv.writer(fp)
        for y in years:
            current_url = url[:-4] +y+ end
            print("current url is: ", current_url)
            data = urlopen(current_url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
            data1 = urlopen(url)
            soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
            for table in soup1.find_all('table',{'id':'statsTable'}):
                url_data[url]["title"].append('year')
                for k in table.find_all('tr'):
                    for n in k.find_all('th'):
                        url_data[url]["title1"].append(n.get_text())
                        for l in url_data[url]["title1"]:
                            if l not in url_data[url]["title"]:
                                url_data[url]["title"].append(l)
                url_data[url]["rows_sp"].append(url_data[url]["title"])
            for table in soup.find_all('table',{'id':'statsTable'}):
                for h in table.find_all('tr'):
                    url_data[url]["row_sp"] = [y]
                    for j in h.find_all('td'):
                        url_data[url]["row_sp"].append(j.get_text().replace(" ","").replace("\n","").replace("\xa0"," ").replace("d",""))
                    url_data[url]["rows_sp"].append(url_data[url]["row_sp"])
                    #print(row_sp)
                    #writer.writerows([row_sp])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

Now for each key `url` in `url_data`, `rows_sp` contains the data you're interested in for that particular url category.
Note that `rows_sp` will now actually be `url_data[url]["rows_sp"]` when we iterate over `url_data`, but the next few code blocks are from my original answer, and so use the old `rows_sp` variable name.

```
# example rows_sp
[['year',
  'RANK THIS WEEK',
  'RANK LAST WEEK',
  'PLAYER NAME',
  'EVENTS',
  'RATING',
  'year',
  'year',
  'year',
  'year'],
 ['2017'],
 ['2017', '1', '1', 'Sam Burns', '1', '9.2'],
 ['2017', '2', '3', 'Rickie Fowler', '10', '8.8'],
 ['2017', '2', '2', 'Dustin Johnson', '10', '8.8'],
 ['2017', '2', '3', 'Whee Kim', '2', '8.8'],
 ['2017', '2', '3', 'Thomas Pieters', '3', '8.8'],
 ...
]
```

Writing `rows_sp` directly to a data frame shows that the data aren't quite in the right format:

```
pd.DataFrame(rows_sp).head()
      0               1               2               3       4       5     6  \
0  year  RANK THIS WEEK  RANK LAST WEEK     PLAYER NAME  EVENTS  RATING  year   
1  2017            None            None            None    None    None  None   
2  2017               1               1       Sam Burns       1     9.2  None   
3  2017               2               3   Rickie Fowler      10     8.8  None   
4  2017               2               2  Dustin Johnson      10     8.8  None   

      7     8     9  
0  year  year  year  
1  None  None  None  
2  None  None  None  
3  None  None  None  
4  None  None  None  

pd.DataFrame(rows_sp).dtypes
0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
4    object
5    object
6    object
7    object
8    object
9    object
dtype: object
```

With a little cleanup, we can get `rows_sp` into a data frame with appropriate numeric data types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows_sp, columns=rows_sp[0]).drop(0)
df.columns = ["year","RANK THIS WEEK","RANK LAST WEEK",
              "PLAYER NAME","EVENTS","RATING",
              "year1","year2","year3","year4"]
df.drop(["year1","year2","year3","year4"], 1, inplace=True)
df = df.loc[df["PLAYER NAME"].notnull()]
df = df.loc[df.year != "year"]
num_cols = ["RANK THIS WEEK","RANK LAST WEEK","EVENTS","RATING"]
df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)

df.head()
   year  RANK THIS WEEK  RANK LAST WEEK     PLAYER NAME  EVENTS  RATING
2  2017               1             1.0       Sam Burns       1     9.2
3  2017               2             3.0   Rickie Fowler      10     8.8
4  2017               2             2.0  Dustin Johnson      10     8.8
5  2017               2             3.0        Whee Kim       2     8.8
6  2017               2             3.0  Thomas Pieters       3     8.8
```

**UPDATED CLEANING**
Now that we have a series of url categories to contend with, each with a different set of fields to clean, the above section gets a little more complicated.  If you only have a few pages, it may be feasible to just visually review the fields for each category, and store them, like this:

```
cols = {'stat.02568.html':{'columns':['year', 'RANK THIS WEEK', 'RANK LAST WEEK', 
                                      'PLAYER NAME', 'ROUNDS', 'AVERAGE', 
                                      'TOTAL SG:APP', 'MEASURED ROUNDS', 
                                      'year1', 'year2', 'year3', 'year4'],
                           'numeric':['RANK THIS WEEK', 'RANK LAST WEEK', 'ROUNDS', 
                                      'AVERAGE', 'TOTAL SG:APP', 'MEASURED ROUNDS',]
                          },
        'stat.111.html':{'columns':['year', 'RANK THIS WEEK', 'RANK LAST WEEK', 
                                    'PLAYER NAME', 'ROUNDS', '%', '# SAVES', '# BUNKERS', 
                                    'TOTAL O/U PAR', 'year1', 'year2', 'year3', 'year4'],
                         'numeric':['RANK THIS WEEK', 'RANK LAST WEEK', 'ROUNDS',
                                   '%', '# SAVES', '# BUNKERS', 'TOTAL O/U PAR']
                        },
        'stat.02356.html':{'columns':['year', 'RANK THIS WEEK', 'RANK LAST WEEK',
                                      'PLAYER NAME', 'EVENTS', 'RATING', 
                                      'year1', 'year2', 'year3', 'year4'],
                           'numeric':['RANK THIS WEEK', 'RANK LAST WEEK', 
                                      'EVENTS', 'RATING']
                          }
       }
```

And then you can loop over `url_data` again and store in a `dfs` collection:

```
dfs = {}

for url in url_data:
    page = url.split("/")[-1]
    colnames = cols[page]["columns"]
    num_cols = cols[page]["numeric"]
    rows_sp = url_data[url]["rows_sp"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows_sp, columns=rows_sp[0]).drop(0)
    df.columns = colnames
    df.drop(["year1","year2","year3","year4"], 1, inplace=True)
    df = df.loc[df["PLAYER NAME"].notnull()]
    df = df.loc[df.year != "year"]
    # tied ranks (e.g. "T9") mess up to_numeric; remove the tie indicators.
    df["RANK THIS WEEK"] = df["RANK THIS WEEK"].str.replace("T","")
    df["RANK LAST WEEK"] = df["RANK LAST WEEK"].str.replace("T","")
    df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    dfs[url] = df
```

At this point, we're ready to `merge` all the different data categories by `year` and `PLAYER NAME`.  (You could actually have merged iteratively in the cleaning loop, but I'm separating here for demonstrative purposes.)

```
master = pd.DataFrame()
for url in dfs:
    if master.empty:
        master = dfs[url]
    else:
        master = master.merge(dfs[url], on=['year','PLAYER NAME'])
```

Now `master` contains the merged data for each player-year.  Here's a view into the data, using `groupby()`:

```
master.groupby(["PLAYER NAME", "year"]).first().head(4)
                  RANK THIS WEEK_x  RANK LAST WEEK_x  EVENTS  RATING  \
PLAYER NAME year                                                       
Aam Hawin   2015                66              66.0       7     8.2   
            2016                80              80.0      12     8.1   
            2017                72              45.0       8     8.2   
Aam Scott   2013                45              45.0      10     8.2   

                  RANK THIS WEEK_y  RANK LAST WEEK_y  ROUNDS_x  AVERAGE  \
PLAYER NAME year                                                          
Aam Hawin   2015               136               136        95   -0.183   
            2016               122               122        93   -0.061   
            2017                56                52        84    0.296   
Aam Scott   2013                16                16        61    0.548   

                  TOTAL SG:APP  MEASURED ROUNDS  RANK THIS WEEK  \
PLAYER NAME year                                                  
Aam Hawin   2015       -14.805               81              86   
            2016        -5.285               87              39   
            2017        18.067               61               8   
Aam Scott   2013        24.125               44              57   

                  RANK LAST WEEK  ROUNDS_y      %  # SAVES  # BUNKERS  \
PLAYER NAME year                                                        
Aam Hawin   2015              86        95  50.96       80        157   
            2016              39        93  54.78       86        157   
            2017               6        84  61.90       91        147   
Aam Scott   2013              57        61  53.85       49         91   

                  TOTAL O/U PAR  
PLAYER NAME year                 
Aam Hawin   2015           47.0  
            2016           43.0  
            2017           27.0  
Aam Scott   2013           11.0
```

You may want to do a bit more cleaning on the merged columns, as some are duplicated across data categories (e.g. `ROUNDS_x` and `ROUNDS_y`).  From what I can tell, the duplicate field names seem to contain exactly the same information, so you might just drop the `_y` version of each one.

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome, I am not going to aggregate data across years, I want to take the data from all the other urls and add to the main dataframe.

Comment: You're welcome!  Did this answer provide sufficient resolution for your initial question?  If so, consider marking this answer accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.   If not, what are you getting stuck on?

Comment: Technically no, but it has answered another question I had,Im getting stuck on making a large dataframe from the information contained in all of the urls with data, Im having trouble merging the data because the way I want to do it is make each urls' data into its own df then merge based on name-year so that each player row has all of the information in one dataframe pulled from each url

Comment: It might help if you add an example of your desired output to your original post, with column names and a few rows of data (even made up data would be useful if it had the correct format).  It's simple enough to make separate data frames for each URL, but I'm still not sure how you intend to merge on player-year if each URL has a different year.  If the practice URL you listed isn't representative of some of the other URLs you want to scrape, consider adding to your practice example the URLs that would give you valid merge possibilities.

Comment: The desired outcomes has been added

Comment: There are a few small error, but I appreciate the help

Comment: If you identify the errors I'm happy to update. This was working correctly when I posted, but I may have had some environment variables hanging around. Does this solution answer your question?

Comment: cols not defined in colnames = cols[page]["columns"]
    num_cols = cols[page]["numeric"],    df = df.loc[df.year != "year"] gives ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Comment: `cols` is defined. See block after Updated Cleaning. This may resolve the multiindex error also.

Comment: I see, I also see you anticipated my next question about how to define cols when more urls are added, is there a good way to do this with many urls?

Comment: Yes, but the optimal solution really will depend on your specific case. You could also just forego the cleaning and merge everything, then clean, which may be easier with very large data. But as I wrote, that's a bit out of scope for this question - there's a lot here already. Feel free to open a new question if you're having trouble coming up with a good way to address that.